# Can't get specific file version from git repository using Python

Tags: python, git

I am trying to get specific version of the file from the git repository. In the folder which contains local copy of the repo I am executing following command (using Python script):

```
subprocess.call("C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe show 34f97c9 folder\file.py > D:\file.py")
```

Sadly all I get is:

```
fatal: >: no such path in the working tree.
Use 'git <command> -- <path>...' to specify paths that do not exist locally.
```

When I try same command directly in gitbash (without git patch obviously) it works just fine.

May I kindly ask you for an advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `subprocess.call` invocation has several errors:

- The default is `shell=False`, which means the command is not passed to the shell, but `>` redirection is a shell feature, not built in to Python.  You can capture the output using `subprocess.stdout=subprocess.PIPE` for instance, or you can create a file using os-level routines and pass the file descriptor, or open a stream and pass its `fileno`; or of course you can set `shell=True`.
- With `shell=False`, you should break up the arguments yourself, e.g., `subprocess.call(["command", "arg1", "arg22"])` or `subprocess.call("command arg1 arg2".split())`.  Of course with `shell=True` there's no need for this, as the shell will do it.  (I presume the form with a single string works on Windows anyway, otherwise you would have gotten a different error, and of course `C:...` is not going to work well on Unix/Linux, so perhaps this can be ignored.)
- In general, backslashes within a string literal are escapes.  The string literal you show in your example here includes a backspace and two form-feeds:

  ```
  >>> print("C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe show 34f97c9 folder\file.py > D:\file.py"")
  C:\Program Files\Giin\git.exe show 34f97c9 folder
                                                   ile.py > D:
                                                              ile.py
  >>>
  ```

  You probably want a raw string here, or you can double all your backslashes.

Meanwhile, your git command is valid but may not mean what you intended it to mean:

```
git show revspec path1 [... pathN]
```

means "show a diff<sup>1</sup> for the given revspec, but show only the changes that affect the given path(s)".  If you want to extract a particular file ("blob") from a particular tree or commit, the syntax is:

```
git show revspec:path
```

(note the literal colon `:` between the revision-specifier and the path).

---

<sup>1</sup>This is a regular diff if the specified revision is an ordinary commit, or a combined diff if the specified revision is a merge.

Comment: Thank you very much! Fixing blackslashes and setting shell argument to True helped :)